# how to use orderByChild with startAfter in Realtime Database using Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort orders in descending and start after on particular key but its not working

**nextAfter : -Mk4-n5BnVpwhum62n2g** or any Key / _id

db record:

```
{
  '-Mk4-n5BnVpwhum62n2g': {
    _id: '-Mk4-n5BnVpwhum62n2g',
    createdAt: -1632171667626,
    name: 'abc'
  },
  '-Mk40Ko9DbSeMdjIpY4': {
    _id: '-Mk40Ko9DbSeMdjIpY4',
    createdAt: -1632171809831,    
    name: 'new '
  }
}
```

trying query :

```
query = dbRef.orderByChild('createdAt').startAfter(nextAfter).limitToFirst(limit);
```

Comment: Can you show where is `nextAfter` defined ?>

Comment: in nextAfter i am assign Key value of db

Comment: You are using `orderByChild` so the `startAfter` will be working on createdAt field.

Comment: is there any other way to sort by child and use startafter on ID

Answer (score 3):

The [`startAfter()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#startafter) accepts two parameters - the first is the relevant `orderBy` value and the second is the optional key of the last entry (for when multiple entries have the same value for the `orderBy` criteria). So to correctly paginate the reference, you need to pass the previous entry's `createdAt` value **and** its key.

```js
const baseQuery = dbRef
  .orderByChild('createdAt')
  .limitToFirst(limit);

let pageCount = 0, lastChildOnPage = undefined;
const children = [];

while (true) {
  const pageQuery = pageCount === 0
    ? baseQuery
    : baseQuery
       .startAfter(lastChildOnPage.createdAt, lastChildOnPage.key);
 
  const pageSnapshot = await pageQuery.once('value');

  pageSnapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    children.push({ key: childSnapshot.key, ...childSnapshot.val() });
  })

  const newLastChildOnPage = children[children.length-1];

  if (lastChildOnPage !== newLastChildOnPage) {
    lastChildOnPage = newLastChildOnPage;
    pageCount++;
  } else {
    break; // no more data
  }
}

console.log(`Grabbed ${pageCount} page(s) of data, retrieving ${children.length} children`);
```