# Firebase realtime database pagination not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I have a React page where I load posts from my firebase realtime database.
The database structure is as follows:

```
posts
-abcdefh
  body: 1st post
  createdAt: 1
-ijklmnop
  body: 2nd post
  createdAt: 2
.
.
.
```

I use the below useEffect hook to get the first two posts for the first time.

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        let isMounted = true;
        if (isMounted){
            window.addEventListener('scroll', loadMore);            
            let posts = [];
            fbRef.db.ref().child('/posts').orderByChild('createdAt').limitToFirst(2).on('value', (snapshot)=>{
                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{                
                    posts.push({...childSnapshot.val(), key: childSnapshot.key});
                }); 
                setPosts(posts);
                console.log('post set');            
            });
        }
        return ()=>{isMounted = false; window.removeEventListener('scroll', loadMore);}
    }, []);
```

When scrolled to the bottom of the page, a loadMore() function fires the getPosts() function to get the next 2 posts like this:

```
    const loadMore = ()=>{
        if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop === document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight){
            getPosts();
        }
    }

    //Get the next two posts in the list

    const getPosts = ()=>{
        let posts = [];
        fbRef.db.ref().child('/posts').orderByChild('createdAt').limitToFirst(2).startAfter(last).on('value', (snapshot)=>{
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{                
                posts.push({...childSnapshot.val(), key: childSnapshot.key});
            });
            setPosts(posts);           
        });
    }
```

The state variable "last" is used to keep track of the last post got from the db. This is set in another useEffect hook:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (posts.length>0){
            setLast(posts.at(-1).key);
        }
    }, [posts]);
```

Problem: When the page loads, the first and second posts appear as expected, but on scrolling to the bottom, the same two posts load again even though the startAfter() function is expected to return the next two posts in the list.
How do I get to load the next two posts in the list, when the getPosts() function is fired?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [`startAfter` accepts two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69267358/3068190). Also, don't use `on('value', () => { ... })` here - you are creating a whole bunch of listeners you are only using once. Use `once('value', () => { ... })` or `once('value').then(() => { ... })` instead.

Comment: @samthecodingman thanks for the comment. I finally got that passing the createdAt key to the startAfter function satisfies my requirement. Thanks a ton!